# Get multiple values, selected according to another column, into a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to get multiple values from an array to display in one cell

For example I have the two columns as below

| a | 1 |

| b | 2 |

| c | 1 |

| d | 3 |

| e | 2 |

So if the parameter is 2 the cell would display "be"

I want all the values form the first column where the second column is 1.
I have tried to do this with `dget` but that only returns a single value.  Is there a way to do this with formulas or does it require a Javascript solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `filter` to return only the letters next to "2", and then `join` to join them in one cell.

```
=join("", filter(A1:A, B1:B = 2))
```